# Black dark spot on kitten's face

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

I found this spot on my 7 week old kitten, it doesn't seem to be painful. I tried to clean it using H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> solution - it went away, but 5 days later appeared again together with a new spot on the nose.

Is it an infection? Should I go to vet?

[image]

Comment: In a comment on a deleted post, you said this turned out to be an illness. Can you tell us what the illness was that caused this? It might help future visitors to the site. You can post the information as an answer, and then accept your own answer.

Comment: I see some answers saying metal, I read non toxic ceramic or stainless steel to be the best bowls for animals. Just remember in the summer stainless steel gets hot so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vet said it is feline acne,  most likely caused by using plastic plate;  it is a kind of allergic reaction to plastic and my kitten was too small to clean itself properly.

First, please switch to using plate made of metal instead of plastic.

Second, the best remedy is to dry it with H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> (hydrogen peroxide) solution multiple times for 5-10 minutes, then when it becomes soft try to clean it with dry cotton, but don't scratch the spot. Repeat the process next day until you remove the spot.

Comment: I need to explain why in my edit I modified it to say "H2O2 solution" instead of just "H2O2": it is to make it clear that we are talking about using the diluted, safe product from the pharmacy instead of pure hydrogen peroxide. Pure H2O2 is highly corrosive irritant and an unstable, controlled substance used as rocket propellant, so we don't want anyone to misunderstand using it for medical purposes.