# Why does my cat have two bald spots, and how do I get her to a vet if I cannot drive?

Tags: cats, health, diseases, injury, skin-condition

Due to being on computer i cannot get any pictures to add right now.

a little about my cat:
she is a 6-7 year old tuxedo cat and has no back teeth. She was declawed by her former owners and is severely overweight, yet on a diet as of right now. She did indeed come to us this way. She has severe asthma and a possible skin condition that we aren't quiet sure about.

my cat has two bald spots, one behind her ear and one under her chin.
The one behind her ear feels rough, dry, but other than that, just like normal skin. The one under her chin, though, feels wet and smooth. It has a patch where it feels like skin was torn but I cannot find any cut or visual damage when I look at it. She does not have flees, and cannot itch as she has no claws. I try to stop her from rubbing her chin against sharp things as much as possible though.

I cannot get her to a vet as I am unable to drive and my parents refuse to take her when they take the dog to the vet. I have tried to convince them twice and they always say "some other time." What do I do?

Comment: Transport is really going to depend where you are. While I can't take a pet on public transport, our one of local uber equivalents has a specific service for that. Also its probably better to focus on 'one' question, the bald spots rather than combining two questions to gether

Comment: Please use the ask button for each single question you have. It is not spam here, to post several questions in several posts :) Have also a look into the linked question and let us know (in comment) if this was helpful: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31587/my-older-cat-is-having-skin-issues-and-my-vet-doesnt-seem-to-know-what-is-wrong/31593#31593

Comment: Have you got a cat carrier? It makes such trips much easier. You can get a small cloth one for round-about $30.

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I have found an article about what can cause bald spots on cats and some natural treatments. I remind you that since this article was not written with your particular problem in mind, your cat could have a completely different problem that could only be diagnosed by a professional veterinarian. It is unfortunate that you do not have access to one at the moment.

There are several things that can cause bald spots. One of which is a dander problem. I hope this is the case, because it only gets worse from here. Another common, yet very treatable problem is ringworm. You've likely heard of ringworm before. Ringworm is a fungal infection that takes place when a very tiny fungus gets under the skin of an animal or human (in this case, a cat.) once there, the fungus basically turns your cat into its home. The balding is caused because the fungus is killing your cat's hair follicles. Another thing that can cause balding is tumors (namely skin cancer). Unfortunately, skin cancer is quite common. While it is common, it is also treatable. Usually, a vet can surgically remove a tumor if there is one, but considering that you do not have access to a vet, I would seriously hope it is not a tumor, since if left untreated it can be fatal.

The chances of it being something serious are low. I remind you once again that this website is **NOT** a substitute for advice from a vet that actually has an visual of the problem and proper tools to treat it.

Good luck, and I pray it's not something serious.

Comment: Ringworm is not a parasite, or a worm at all. It is a fungal infection (also known as dermatophytosis).

Comment: @HarryV. small grammatical/word choice error. my apologies.